# How can I convert a C-style printf format to a C# string format?

Tags: c#, c, string-formatting

How can I convert the string formatting pattern from C's `printf()` to C# `string.Format()` pattern?

For instance C's `"%04x"` converts to C#'s `"X4"`

Comment: Are there any in particular that you are having problems with?

Comment: "%04x" converts to "x4". Notice the case difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting one string pattern to another string pattern is best achieved with regex I think. (That would be my approach if the problem is generic or perhaps limited to a few sections of interest.)

If you're after the printf in .net, it could be solved with a lib: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19274/A-printf-implementation-in-C
https://sourceforge.net/projects/printfnet/

Or with pinvoke to the real printf:
http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/28/4473.aspx

A generic approach to converting a printf pattern to string.format could perhaps be extracted from one of the two (open source) libs.